# error in displaying data tables for specific id in codeigniter sql

Tags: javascript, sql, codeigniter

excuse me sir/ma'am
I'm trying retrieve data from SQL database to display something like a transaction data in data tables for a specific id, but I got the error saying : `Too few arguments to function`
say I have

```
client a
client b
client c
```

when I click `client a`, it retrieves all data for `client a` and it goes something like

```
client a     06-07-2019   $500
client a     15-07-2019   $750
client a     22-07-2019   $340
```

I've tried to use `$this->input->get('id')` but it seems like it doesn't detect the `id` when I send it to the model
here is the URL pattern, and the `id` I'm trying to get

https://dev3.gatra.com/bisdev/bmitra/commission?id=34

here is the function to call the data

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        
        table = $('#commision').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "order": [],
            "oLanguage": {
                    "sSearch": "Search :"
                    },

            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('bmitra/get_dataserverside_commission')?>",
                "type": "POST",
                "data" : {},
                beforeSend:function () {
                    $("#progressbottom").show();
                },
                complete:function () {
                    $("#progressbottom").hide();
                    $(".tooltip").tooltip("hide");
                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                }
            },
            
            "columnDefs": [
            { "orderable": false, "targets": [5]  },
            { "className": "style1", "targets": [ 0,1,2,3,4,5 ] }
            ],

        });

        
    });
```

here is the code for controller

```php
function get_dataserverside_commission(){
      // $data['commision']=$this->Bmitra_m->_get_datatables_query_commission();
        
      $data = $this->input->get('id');
      $list = $this->Bmitra_m->get_datatables_commission($data);
      $data = array(
                'id' => $data,
      );
      $no = $_POST['start'];
      foreach ($list as $field) {
            
          $option='<center>'             
                 .'<button type="button" title="Hapus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Hapus" data-id="' 
                 . $field->id . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="showpop('.$field->id
                 .')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>'              
                 .'</center>';
           
          
          $row = array();       
          $row[] = $field->id;        
          $row[] = $field->company_name;
          $row[] = $field->from;
          $row[] = $field->to;
          $row[] = $field->commission;
          $row[] = $option;
          // $row[] = '-';
          // $row[] = '-';
          // $row[] = '-';
          // $row[] = '-';
          $data[] = $row;
      }

      $output = array(
          "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
          "recordsTotal" => $this->Bmitra_m->count_all_commission(),
          "recordsFiltered" => $this->Bmitra_m->count_filtered_commission(),
          "data" => $data,
      );
      // $this->db->close();
      //output dalam format JSON
      echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

here is code for the model

```php
private function _get_datatables_query_commission($id)
    {  
        // $id = $this->input->post('commissionid');
        $this->db->select('a.company_name,b.*'); 
        $this->db->from('bis_mitra a');
        $this->db->join('bis_set_commission b','a.id = b.bismitra_id','left');
        $this->db->where('a.id' , $id); 
        $this->db->where('a.active', 1);
        $this->db->where('a.trash', 0);
                 
        $i = 0;  

        foreach ($this->column_search_commission as $item) // looping awal
        {
           if($_POST['search']['value']) // jika datatable mengirimkan pencarian dengan metode POST
           {
              if($i===0) // looping awal
              {
                 $this->db->group_start();
                 $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
              }
              else
              {
                 $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
              }
              if(count($this->column_search_commission) - 1 == $i)
                 $this->db->group_end();
           }
           $i++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order']))
        {
           $this->db->order_by($this->column_order_commission[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        }
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
           $order = $this->order;
           $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

// there are 2 function for the model

function get_datatables_commission($id){
         $this->_get_datatables_query_commission($id);
         if($_POST['length'] != -1)
         $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
         $query = $this->db->get();
         return $query->result();
    }
```

any help and explanation would be appreciated
thank you!

Comment: you  should pass id in query string. Will you please share url pattern,  how you are calling get_dataserverside_commission function?

Comment: i've edited the question sir, please look into it

Comment: please share showpop function code.

Comment: function showpop(id){
        $('#id_mitra').val(id);
        $('#id_mitra2').html(id);
        $('#delete_modal').modal('show');
    }
but its on different page
i think thats only for deleting the data

Comment: do not use left join, since it will give you all the data from left table even if data  not found in right table. use inner join.

Comment: i've tried to tweak here and there but still got the same error, i'm using the input ->get->id

Answer (score 0):

Your `$data` needs data from  `id` from `$_GET` but the `id value` is not passed in the datatable ajax

Try like this,

```
//Datatable 

 "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('bmitra/get_dataserverside_commission'. ($id ? '/' . $id: ''))?>",
                "type": "POST",
                "data" : {},
                beforeSend:function () {
                    $("#progressbottom").show();
                },
                complete:function () {
                    $("#progressbottom").hide();
                    $(".tooltip").tooltip("hide");
                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                }
            }

// get_dataserverside_commission

   function get_dataserverside_commission($id = NULL){
      $data = $id ? $id : NULL;
      echo $data;
   }
```